# Generating surface mesh from point cloud using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, mesh

I am trying to generate a surface from a point cloud [image: scatter plot]. I have looked around and the solution seems to generate triangles from the cloud point to then produce the final mesh. However, I tried to follow the procedure proposed [here](https://plotly.com/python/trisurf/) but I failed and obtained this: [image: trisurf attempt]

Sadly, my background in math is not quite good and when I started to read about Jonathan Shewchuk from other awnsers and tessellation from the Plotly documentation, I didn't really follow.

The code I used is this:

```
#Assume X_Vir, Y_Vir and Z_Vir are list of points used to create the scatter plot

points2D = np.vstack([X_Vir, Y_Vir]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)    
simplices = tri.simplices
fig = ff.create_trisurf(x=X_Vir, y=Y_Vir, z=Z_Vir, simplices=simplices)
fig.show()
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my issue by providing points coordinates as well as the associated vertices using the `Mesh3d` function of plotly:

```
fig = pot.Figure(data=[pot.Mesh3d(x=points_coord90[:,1], y=points_coord90[:,0], z=points_coord90[:,2], 
                        i=points_vert[:,0], j=points_vert[:,1], k=points_vert[:,2], 
                        intensity=bi_volt, cmin=0, cmax=2, reversescale=False, colorscale='RdYlBu', opacity=1)])

fig.show()
```

[image: mesh1]
If you don't have the vertices, another possibility is to use the [alphahull](https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/) option (rather than the Delaunay) of plotly but it didn't fullfilled my needs:

```
fig = pot.Figure(data=[pot.Mesh3d(x=points_coord90[:,1], y=points_coord90[:,0], z=points_coord90[:,2], alphahull=0.5, opacity=0.5)])
```